# How to make somethinge like the iPad/iPhone main menu?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

No need to say I'm an absolute beginner in Xcode, after you read my question:

In my app I'm putting together, as menu, 5 pics, fulfilling the whole screen in portrait. I'm using UISwipeGestureRecognizer for each view so the user will be able to go left and right through all of them. My problem is that the transition goes very dry and instantaneous, without any animation. So, my question is what should I use, to obtain this cool effect of the views, snapping to the screen boundaries, when the user takes out his finger? 
You know, just like the main menu of the iPad, when you go through the pages with your apps and before swiping a page all the way to the end and let go, the page snaps with a little jerky adjustment.
I,ve looked everywhere and could not find anything on that on the net.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers
Ioan

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [three20](http://three20.info/) library. It does this and much more. Specifically look at the [launcher](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher) feature.

Comment: Thank you very mach for your answer Alex.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add in your own animations and effects yourself if you aren't using a 3rd party utility (I don't know of one that does what you want).

For instance, if you wanted your icons to center on the screen smoothly, maybe setup a timer that triggers every 100 milliseconds for .5 seconds so that after the .5 seconds are up, the icons are centered.

As soon as the user lifts their finger after a swipe take the center position, how far away the icons are from the center, and divide by 5 and move by that much each timer activation.

That's a simple example, but I think you get the idea.